# Reference Variable names as strings

Tags: vb.net, variables, dll, reflection, class-library

I am trying to reference the name of a variable as a string. I have a list of global variables

```
Public gvHeight As String = Blank
Public gvWeight As String = Blank
Public gvAge As String = Blank
```

I need to reference the name of the variables for an external API call. I am trying to avoid specific code per variable, instead allow me to add a new variable and everything reference correctly. I already have the rest of the code to deal with the name as a string.

example:

```
public Height as string
public weight as string
public age as string

[elsewhere in code]
for each var as string in {public variables}
   CallToAPI(var.name) 'needs to send "height" "weight" or "age" but there are a lot so hardcoding is not a good solution
```

edited for example

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Can you provide a pseudo-code sample which demonstrates what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You could put them in a dictionary. But what you are asking sounds weird.

Comment: Hard to imagine and API which works off names rather than values...smells like an XY problem

Comment: @Plutonix - The API has a call "GetField(program_reference,field_Name_As_String,Output_Buffer,Max_Size). I could need any number of fields related to the single call (it has close to 100 possible field names)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the public fields through **Reflection**.

Having an example dll compiled from this source-code:

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Field1 As String = "value 1"
    Public Field2 As String = "value 2"
    Public Field3 As Integer

End Class
```

Then you could do this:

```
' The library path.
Dim libpath As String = "...\ClassLibrary1.dll"

' The assembly.
Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(libpath)

' The Class1 type. (full namespace is required)
Dim t As Type = ass.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1", throwOnError:=True)

' The public String fields in Class1.
Dim strFields As FieldInfo() =
    (From f As FieldInfo In t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public)
     Where f.FieldType Is GetType(String)
    ).ToArray

' A simple iteration over the fields to print their names.
For Each field As FieldInfo In strFields
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name)
Next strField
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your variables are of the same type (here strings), you can use a Dictionary...

```
Public MyModule
  Private myVars As Dictionary(Of String, String)

  Public Function CallToAPI(VarName As String) As String
      If myVars.ContainsKey(VarName) Then
          Return myVars(VarName)
      End If
      Return ""
  End Function
End Module
```

And somewhere else in your external code

Module TestModule

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim myVar = MyModule.CallToAPI("test")

End Sub
```

End Module

Now if your variables aren't the same, then you must use Reflection... and that's where the fun begins...